# Babel-node ignores or misbehaves when I add ignore option to babel.config.js

Tags: node.js, babeljs, babel-node

am using the command

```
npx babel-node --ignore=' ' --extensions='.ts,.tsx,.js,.jsx,.es6,.es' test.js
```

to compile the script named **test.js** .

**test.js** imports `import template from 'lodash-es/template';` and I would like it to be compiled too.

Adding **ignore** or **include** or **exclude** options regex at babel.config.js doesn't work.
How do i add an inline `--ignore` option (`{ ignore: [/node_modules\/(?!lodash-es)/] }`) like babel.config.js?
Why does `{ ignore: [/node_modules\/(?!lodash-es)/] }`  work with **`@babel/register`** and not with **`babel.config.js`** ?

Below is test.js:

```
import fs from 'fs';
import template from 'lodash-es/template';
console.log(template);

export default function () {

};
```

package.json:

```
"@babel/cli": "^7.7.7",
"@babel/core": "^7.7.7",
"@babel/node": "^7.8.4",
```

Problem seems to be similar to https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/6229

Answer (score 3):

I resolved the issue with: **`--ignore="/node_modules\/(?\!lodash-es)/"`**

`npx babel-node --config-file="./babel.config.js" --ignore="/node_modules\/(?\!lodash-es)/" --extensions='.ts,.tsx,.js,.jsx,.es6,.es' test.js`

using **`--ignore=' '`** will also work, but you may start getting

```
[BABEL] Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of {filename} as it exceeds the max of 500KB.
```

because Babel will compile all imported **`node_modues`**, which is quite expensive.

Comment: The argument works well. Is it possible to hide --ignore argument into a settings file babel.config.js. I tried to do it. But it didn't affect.